# Scala: Generate a block that conditionally runs another block

Tags: scala, codeblocks

In the [Circumflex framework](http://lkjjj), you can map an URL to a block like this:

```
get("/foo") = {
    "hello, world!"
}
```

which, when browsing to `/foo`, will show the given string as expected. Now, to write a complete web application, you almost always need some form of authentication and authorisation. I'm trying to write some kind of wrapper for the above construct, so I can write this:

```
get("/foo") = requireLogin {
    "hello, world!"
}
```

The `requireLogin` method would then check if the user is logged in, and if yes, execute the given block. If not, however, it should do a redirect to the login page.

Now I somehow can't get the syntax right (i'm still a Scala newbie). How would you do this in a generic fashion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
def executeMaybe[A](work: => A): Option[A] =
  if (util.Random.nextBoolean)
    Some(work)
  else
    None
```

This executes the passed code with probability 0.5, returning `Some(<result delivered by work>)`, or returns `None` is the other cases. You can call it either like this:

```
val v = executeMaybe(42)
```

or with block notation:

```
val v = executeMaybe {
  // do some work
  // provide return value
}
```

The trick is to use a *by-name parameter*, signalled by the `=>` symbol. Read more e.g. here: http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2009/12/by-name-parameter-to-function.html

Answer (score 3):

The way I asked it, Jean-Philippe's answer is correct. 
But here's some information specific to Circumflex:

In the Circumflex `RequestRouter`, the following can be used to implement the required method:

```
def requireLogin (f: => RouteResponse ): RouteResponse = {
    if(loggedIn) {
        return f
    }
    else {
        return sendRedirect("/login")
    }
}
```

The reason behind this was getting clear with the hint from Jean-Philippe's answer, and once I remembered that the following call isn't an assignment of a block to some internal data, but is mapped to another method call instead.

So, the call

```
get("/") = {...}
```

is actually mapped to this:

```
get.update("/", {...})
```

The block is passed in as a By-Name parameter, so the return value of `requireLogin` must be the same - which, for Circumflex, is `RouteResponse`, and not a function.

Answer (score -1):

You also can use j2ee container authentication with `<login-config>` and `<security-constraint>` stuff inside web.xml