# How to write your own matcher in Circumflex?

Tags: scala

As asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6641864/35189), I need to run a Circumflex action only if a condition is met. Currently, I do it like this:

```
get("/") = requireLogin {
    ...
}
```

Now Circumflex supports Matchers, which can be put right within the `get()` specification:

```
get("/mail" & Host("localhost"))
```

How can I write my own matcher, so the above `requireLogin` gets closer to the Circumflex style? I wish to write something like this:

```
get("/" & IsLoggedIn) = {
    ...
}
```

Comment: you can write something like this now:

   get("/?).and(IsLoggedIn) = {
     ...
   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple implementation. All it takes is to define an object with the desired name, extending from `AtomicMatcher` (as this one implements `add()` etc) and implement the `name` and `apply` methods:

```
object IsLoggedIn extends AtomicMatcher {
    def name = "IsLoggedIn"

    def apply = {
        // Not shown: figuring out whether user is logged in or not
        if(loggedIn) {
            Some(List(new MatchResult(name)))
        }
        else {
            sendRedirect("/login")
            throw new ResponseSentException;
        }
    }
}
```

If the user is logged in (ie. the action can be executed), you need to return a list of at least one `MatchResult`. If you don't want to execute the action, do something else and either return `None` or throw a `ResponseSentException`, [which seems to be the preferred way](http://circumflex.ru/docs/web/basic.html).